# how to write dynamic route in nginx location proxy config

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

for example I want anyone hits `localhost/api` to be redirected to a proxy of `127.0.0.1/api` and whatever after it, for example, if I got `localhost/api/getMyName` then the config redirect it to `127.0.0.1/api/getMyName`. or if someone hits `localhost/api/getSomeone/1`, it will proxy to  `127.0.0.1/api/getSomeone/1`

I tried something like

```
location /api {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/api;
    }
```

But the nginx just not responding at or, and adding `/*` or `*` after them just do not do the work... what should it actually be written to match the scenario I want above?